# Formatted emails does not display properly on gmail

Tags: css, google-apps-script, gmail, html-email, mix-blend-mode

I use Apps Script to send formatted emails via MailApp.sendEmail function.

1. Users can configure e-mail in a variety of ways in my web application
2. After that my application sends this informations to the .gs file
3. Then Apps Script creates template from HTML file and sends it via sendEmail function
4. Everything looks fine until... you open this email in gmail mailbox.

And this is where the fun begins. Sometimes everything looks fine and sometimes some text is hidden by an invisible element (I have no idea what it is, it has rounded shape when I don't use any roundings in my e-mail). Often this element does not appear until the resolution is reduced (or increased), sometimes it appears immediately.

[image: bug]

[image]

As this problem only occurs on computers in gmail mailbox (on phone and on other mailbox email looks fine) my prime suspect is blend mode (I used it to fix colors on iOS Gmail App Dark mode).

```css
div { flex-grow:1; }
u + .body .gmail-blend-screen { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:screen;}
u + .body .gmail-blend-screen-title { mix-blend-mode:screen;}
u + .body .gmail-blend-difference { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:difference;}
u + .body .gmail-blend-title { ;mix-blend-mode:initial;}
```

How I use it:

```html
   <div class="gmail-blend-screen">
    <div class="gmail-blend-difference">
       W razie jakichkolwiek pytań proszę o kontakt.<br>
       Serdecznie pozdrawiam
    </div>
   </div>
```

So I want to ask:

1. What causes an invisible field to appear obscuring the text? (I can send you more code if you think it's not the blend's fault)
2. How to fix it?

**EDIT:** I have just checked my thesis and managed to confirm it, blend mode is to blame.

I have 2 blend modes - one of them is difference, second one is initial. I use first one to change the black text into white (on dark mode). Second one is for changing green text into other color (because difference mode makes it pink).

How I want to use it:

```html
<div class="gmail-blend-screen-title">
  <div class="gmail-blend-title">
    <p class="title">***TITLE GREEN TEXT CHANGED TO GREEN ON DARK MODE***</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gmail-blend-screen">
  <div class="gmail-blend-difference">
    NORMAL WHITE TEXT CHANGED TO WHITE ON DARK MODE
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:** After hours of tests I found another fact - this problem occurs when I use more than one div with blend class. I have to use multiple divs because I have two images between body and footer of my email and I don't want them to be blended. You can find some hints below:

```
<!-- THIS CODE WORKS WELL BUT I CAN NOT USE IT BECAUSE OF IMAGES -->
<div class="main-div-with-background">
  <div class="gmail-blend-screen">
     <div class="gmail-blend-difference">
       ** FULL EMAIL **
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- THIS CODE CAUSES PROBLEM WITH INVISIBLE TEXT -->
<div class="main-div-with-background">
  <div class="gmail-blend-screen">
     <div class="gmail-blend-difference">
       ** FULL EMAIL **
     </div>
  </div>
  <table> ** TABLE WITH IMAGES ** </table>
  <div class="gmail-blend-screen">
     <div class="gmail-blend-difference">
       ** FOOTER **
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's why its not working : https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-mix-blend-mode/

Comment: @WaximCorp it's working as it should everywhere, but problem is how it works on gmail.

Comment: In order to know how to fix it we would have to know what it should look like

Comment: @Cooper hope my explaination in edit will be enough

Comment: I my case I don't know what it is supposed to look like visually.  So the question is it supposed to look like?

Comment: @Cooper I have dark-green image as a background and white letters. When you switch to dark mode on iOS this letters turns to black color when background is still dark-green what makes them unreadable. I used Gmail blend mode to fix it and change them to white color on dark mode. And that's how I want it. White letters no matter what mode you use. It worked, but I just realized that there is a strange invisible element covering letters when you zoom in or out. Now, I just want to find another solution for iOS dark mode or solution for removing this invisible element.

Comment: I understand what you are doing, and it all makes sense. There is no known alternative solution. I don't know how many people zoom on a mobile- so maybe it's not actually an issue?

Comment: @Nathan "As this problem only occurs on computers in gmail mailbox"

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fix, but I have more info. I have been investigating this for quite some time as we often have the same problem, because we use the same "hack" of applying blend modes to control dark mode styles.

I haven't found definitive proof but I believe that it is a z-index or [composite layer](https://github.com/vasanthk/browser-rendering-optimization/blob/master/README.md) issue. For blending to work, the browser needs to essentially stack items in new layers. At that point, something in the Gmail web UI is also on that layer and they collide.

It only happens for us in certain browser sizes (around the size of 12" MBP and Macbook Airs) 1200ish by 600ish, so I believe a non-visible element has space in the DOM there.

You can verify that is likely a layering issue by altering the z-index of the email container or anything else. I'll share a screenshot of the bug and then how resetting everything to set z-index fixes it.

[image: the bug]
[image: resetting z-index as a fix]

Since we'd need Gmail to fix the z-index, we've instead started avoiding using the hack and letting the Gmail app destroy our emails with their dark mode colors that can't be overridden.